# A desktop app by integrating asana API

Tags: asana

I am working on some project by integrating asana API into a desktop app. or a dashboard page. I am just beginner in programming, would you please tell where to start? I have looked into the Asana Chrome Extension example, and I am not sure what language should I use to create desktop app.. In the hello world example, you use Ruby, is it comparatively easy to start with Ruby, I know a little on Ruby. Is Java possible? Please tell me whatever you think is helpful for me in constructing a app.

Thanks a lot.

BOB

Comment: What's the target platform? Windows, MacOS, Linux, all of the above?

Comment: To Seva, Thanks a lot. My target is Windows.

Comment: You say you're just a beginner. What language are you most familiar with? Also, is outsourcing/delegating an option?

Comment: no. I will do myself and I am learning. Java, JavaScript, PHP, Ruby are the languages I am familiar with in the decreasing order. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Then go with Java. You can do desktop software with Java. You'll have to learn some GUI library - there are several.

Answer (score 1):

Since this question seems to be not resolved, even it's more than 2 years old. I've not developped nothing using Asana API, but it's a RESTful interface, so you may be able to do HTTP resquests using Java. You'll have to use some library to parse JSON or do it yourself. I recomend Google's GSON library to deal with JSON.

In the following link you will find the API documentation. Ignore the right column with the ruby example, and look at the left column whhere you have deatiled all the URL's that their API provide.
http://developer.asana.com/documentation

If you don't matter to use other language instead of Java, you could use an unofficial client library.
http://developer.asana.com/developer-showcase/

I hope this response could satisfy your needs or those of who get into a similar situation.